# Why is the Form tag in ASP.NET MasterPage breaking CSS formatting by bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, master-pages

I am a new ASP.NET Webforms developer and I am trying to do a test application in ASP.NET where I can use it with Bootstrap. I already have a bootstrap template that I used with other projects and it works so well. However, when I integrated it with ASP.NET MasterPage, I got something really weired and I don't know why.

Kindly note that I am using Bootstrap 3.2 and I put all of the custom style of the template in another file called style.css.

**Could you please help me in this regard and tell me how to resolve this issue?**

A snapshot of the right style and the look and feel of the system (desired result):

[image]

A snapshot of the undesired result:

[image]

Here's a [JSFiddle file](https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/qp6xeyq5/2/) that includes HTML and my css file, style.css. I appologize for the bad formatting and use of JSFiddle as I am totally new to this website.

All what I have done so far with ASP.NET MasterPage is copying whatever I have in the html page and embed it in the MasterPage within

```
<form runat="server"></form>
```

UPDATE:
**How can I modify the CSS to recognize the main form tag in the ASP.NET MasterPage?**

Comment: If you compare the rendered html/css using MasterPage with the bootstrap html/css, you should be able to figure it out. As for us to help, we need to see them to, not only as image dumps.

Comment: I already provided you with the css in the JSFiddle file.

Comment: I have corrected the jsfiddle, including the correct bootstrap css and jquery, but the header is white now

Comment: @silviagreen thanks for your help. I think it is white because the background in css is using an image that is in my machine.

Comment: I cannot help much without the full code, here: https://jsfiddle.net/qp6xeyq5/3/ i only added some colors in background and put the down arrow in the circle in a new row, so it cannot overlap the other elements of the page when resizing the screen